# Is there a hypernym of actual & basic [price / weight]?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms, common-word

Is there a hypernym of 'actual' & 'basic' in this usage?

For example:

> - The actual price can be higher than the basic price because of fees etc.

or

> - The actual weight can be higher than the basic weight because of packaging.

Comment: Hello, Igor. I'm unfamiliar with the string 'declared price'; on looking it up, I think it is a legally defined term in some industries.  I assume you mean 'basic price'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Yes, English is not my mother tongue so this word didn't entered my mind. I've updated prices example to clarify it. However question is not about just hypernym for prices with or without fees and taxes. I need something more "categorial", some common term for what you can see on a paper and what it really means. However if there is such word for prices it would be great to see such example.

Comment: There's nothing unusual here. What you seem to be describing should be the main point of every text on import and export.

There ain't no such animal as your hypernym. If there were, it would be more confusing than helpful. What difference d'you claim between "actual" and "basic", please?

When you say "The actual price can be higher than the basic price because (anything)…" that is at least to confuse cost with price.

Similarly, "the actual… can be higher than the basic weight because of packaging" is to ignore all the details, however clearly they were stated.

Comment: Wouldn't the hypernym of *basic* weight, *actual* weight and *any kind of* weight be just *weight* (and likewise for *price*)?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone in business should understand "nett" and "gross" - which seems to be what Igor Mikushkin is asking about - but in all seriousness how should we even spell "nett", let alone define a price as "nett (of what, exactly)"?

Some industries - as for instance, transport leasing - use terms such as "wet" and "dry" to state whether you're renting, for instance, an aircraft with or without a crew but what else might the aircraft come without? Maintenance, for one…

Other fields of transport will describe shipping costs as "landed" or "free and clear" or other jargon terms and should the fact you've been happily discussing every little detail with a particular supplier for years without end, give you the confidence to sign a contract with anyone else using exactly the same terms in *apparently* the same way?

If it matters, be specific; otherwise, be prepared to pay for generality.

Comment: Typically spelled "[net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(economics))"

Answer (score 0):

Contextual Hypernyms:

A proper word for 'actual and basic' needs to be based on context. A word that would mean both 'actual and basic' indicates the speaker is expressing a move away from precision, which may be for various contextual reasons. Some words that would fit in various contexts would be:

- Declared - Announced formally or officially. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/declare#English
  Declared might be imprecision resulting from being in a legal context.
- Expressed - Conveyed or communicated; made known or explicit  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/express#English
  Expressed might be imprecision resulting from a conversational context.
- Stated - Expressed in a statement; uttered or written.    https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stated
  Stated might be imprecision from a debate or political context.
- Supposed - Presumed to be true, but without proof https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supposed
  Supposed might be in a context where the imprecision is acknowledged.
- Nominal - Existing in name only.  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nominal
  Nominal might be in a technical context where precision has been lost somehow or the information conveyed by the statement is known to be incomplete.

There are many more possibilities based on many more contexts.

Direct Hypernyms:

For situations where we want to convey 'both the basic and the actual' the word might be multifarious. These are also contextual but in this case the context is who you are talking to rather than the context of the statement.

- Multifarious - made up of many differing parts;   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multifarious For example "the multifarious weight is 237 kg base weight, 245 kg with packaging". But multifarious is a very uncommon word. This isn't quite the correct use of the word, but it is so uncommon that people will assume you are using this hypernym correctly and glean its meaning by context.
- Multivalued - associating one or more values of its range with each value of its domain. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multivalued If you don't mind sounding like a mathematician, this word might work as a good hypernym.
- Structured (programming) - Structures represent a "named" collection of related data. https://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/structures.html If you use structured as your hypernym, a programmer will probably get what you're talking about. Most other people won't.

Comment: While this is true, the question is asking for a hypernym.

Comment: Multifarious would be the hypernym. Using the examples given: "The multfarious price includes the actual price and the basic price where the actual price can be higher than the basic price because of fees."

Comment: Another word that might come a little closer would be 'multi-valued'. It might make sense to add this to my answer, although it is specifically mathematics language [added]. A programmer would use the word 'structured'.